# What's the most ancient language to be reconstructed?

Tags: historical-linguistics

What is the most ancient language that is reconstructed to a point that it is actually possible to learn it and to use it?
I am especially interested in Proto-Indo-European (and even in Proto-Nostratic but I don‘t know if this is a real language or just an hypothesis).

I know that [Sambahsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambahsa) in based on PIE but as far as I understand it's more an inspiration that a reconstruction.

Comment: Just to be clear, all reconstructed languages are hypotheses. It is true however that PIE is much more widely accepted a hypothesis than Proto-Nostratic. Further, there are very few reconstructed languages (as far as I know) that can actually be learnt and used.

Comment: What I meant was that I don't think Proto-Nostratic is accepted as a thing among linguists and that PIE is almost unquestionable (again, this is just how I perceive the opinion of the scientific community)

Comment: Even PIE is just a set of formulae. There are no PIE texts, or even sentences. Or sounds. Let alone constructions, idioms, greetings, insults, or mocking language. Those are things that real languages with real living speech groups have;  it's those languages that one can learn to speak, if one is lucky. PIE isn't one of them. Barring the invention of time machines, it won't ever be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I thought the grammar was partly reconstructed through comparative linguistics. And with this grammar and all the words we indirectly know, can't we make sentences. Sorry if my questions are a bit naive

Comment: The grammar has indeed been reconstructed to some degree through comparative linguistics. But there is far less reliable information about syntax than morphology, and even for the morphology, we have no way to tell whether two particular constructions were spoken either at the same time, or in the same dialect.

Comment: There are absolutely reconstructed sentences and texts written in reconstructed PIE; I myself have sung many a song composed in PIE at uni Christmas parties (e.g., _Ei̯ seno-g̑néh₃tis mr̥sh₁i̯ētor_ – aka _Auld Lang Syne_. But they are all _reconstructed_, which means you’re quite likely to find lots of people who will consider them completely wrong. As Colin says, any such composition is inherently uncertain, to the point that we have no idea if an actual speaker from back then would be able to make sense of a single word of it.